# IUSR_machinename Group Membership?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2003, iis-6

I've been searching for a while and am having trouble finding the answer.

I have an IIS6 server running WebDAV for HTTP PUT uploads through anonymous access.  The uploads work fine and the newly created files have a Creator/Owner of `<machinename>\IUSR_<machinename>` as expected.  The problem I'm having is that I can overwrite files but I can't find the permission that allows it.

For a file, if I do a `Get-ChildItem <filename>.txt | Get-Acl | fl` in Powershell, I have the following info:

```
PS x:\> Get-ChildItem <somefile>.txt | Get-Acl | fl


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::x:\<somefile>.txt
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : CCTLAB\Domain Users
Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)
```

I'm thinking that maybe IUSR_ is in one of these groups, but I'm not certain which one.  Is IUSR_ a member of `Authenticated Users` or `Users`, maybe?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323640

Comment: Also, are you sure it's using the IUSR user and not the IWAM user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IUSR_<machinenname>` is a member of `Authenticated Users` and `Users` group (which makes sense; the IUSR account has a sid and all that).  techie007's [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323640) is quite helpful.